# Gravity Form doesn't work with Checkout Page

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart, gravity-forms-plugin

I have one Gravity Form, Once user specified the details, go to checkout page, Rather than goes to checkout page it shows the variable dump.

```
https://pastebin.com/Dhzgqkwi
https://prnt.sc/r1l6n6
```

But I configured the same remote site on my local it works fine.
The different is PHP version.
Mine is 7.x and remote one is 5.x.

```
https://prnt.sc/r1l6rl
```

Where should I check? How should I insert die() command to check the result?

Comment: I finally narrowed down here, but not any more. wp_redirec() function is not working.

 wp_redirect($cartPageLink);
 exit;
I used to have header_already_sent warnings everywhere, so I disabled the error messages in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.
1. The dump code is normal behavior, the problem was not redirecting after dumping the variables.
2. wp_redirect('Cart_Url'); exit;
 This code didn't work which is absolutely normal code. The reason behind this was 'Header already sent warnings'.
3. There was some marketing analysis code added in the beginning of WordPress index.php file like